# How to trigger function on viewport visible with Vue viewport plugin

Tags: vue.js, counter, viewport

I am using an counter to display some numbers, but they load up when the page loads, so it loads unless I do some button to trigger it.
Found this viewport plugin (https://github.com/BKWLD/vue-in-viewport-mixin) but I weren't able to use it. That's what I need to do, trigger a function when I reach some element (entirely), how to achieve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a package to do this. Add an event listener to listen to the scroll event, and check if the element is in the viewport every time there's a scroll event. Example code below - note that I've added an animation to emphasize the "appear if in viewport" effect.

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/CodingDeer/pen/ZgKOJz).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  },
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6, 
        7, 
        8, 
        9, 
        10, 
        11, 
        12
      ],
      offsetTop: 0
    }
  },
  watch: {
    offsetTop (val) {
       this.callbackFunc()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll (e) {
      console.log('scrolling')
      this.offsetTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
    },
    isElementInViewport(el) {
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
      );
    },
    callbackFunc() {
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (this.isElementInViewport(items[i])) {
          items[i].classList.add("in-view");
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.card {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0
}
.in-view {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: bounce-appear .5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce-appear {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) scale(0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    tranform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" onscroll="onScroll">
  <div v-for="item in items" class="card">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to use an intersection observer - I haven't explored this yet but this tutorial seems good: alligator.io/vuejs/lazy-image. Note that you will need a polyfill for IE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I wonder if that would be heavy, since it's updating in every scroll

Comment: It's not updating on every scroll. It's listening on every scroll - there's a difference. I'm not too sure about performance differences, but you can also use an intersection observer for this: https://alligator.io/vuejs/lazy-image/, which is what the package that you directed to is based on. Personally I always prefer creating my own components over using other people's packages for fear of package bloat and versioning issues and for the purpose of learning.

Comment: I suggest replacing `offsetTop: 0` with `offsetTop: window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop`. This should set the correct offset when initially loading the page at a different position - it's not always correct to assume you are at the top position.

Comment: thx for the good job... I would also suggest to add an else to remove in-view class when condition is not in viewport
if (this.isElementInViewport(items[i])) {
          items[i].classList.add("in-view");
        } else { items[i].classList.remove("in-view");}

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something similar using an [Intersection Observer constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/IntersectionObserver)

```js
let observer = null;

onMounted(()=>{
  observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
      threshold: 0.5, // proportion of element visible to trigger action
    });
  observer.observe(refOfElement)
})

const callback = (entry) => {
  // action to trigger
}
```